# Oracle APEX: Is it possible to disable IG select conditionally

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I want to disable select on my IG when a page item P1_CONDITION meets certain criteria. I hid row action and row selector when condition is met, but if I click on any of the rows, they are still getting selected - custom delete button shows up in the toolbar. How can I disable select conditionally?

I know I can add a condition to the DA that takes care of showing or hiding the custom button but I wanted to disable select altogether. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript snippet as below to disable your grid:

```
var grid = apex.region("emp").call("getViews").grid;
grid.view$.grid("option", "editable", false);
grid.model.setOption("editable", false);
```

OR
You can also disable the column you want to disable using Execute Javascript Code action  or  using disable action of dynamic actions as following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the user to click/select the row,

1. Add the below code in the **Execute When Page Loads** section of the page.

```
if ($v("YOUR_ITEM") == 'YOUR_VALUE') {
   $("#emp .a-GV-table tbody .a-GV-row").css('pointer-events','none');
}
```

**Note:** emp is the Static ID of the Interactive Grid.

2. Switch off the **Select First Row** property of the Interactive Grid. 
   [image]